# JndiPermission error on tomcat with security manager and internal URLClassLoader

Tags: java, tomcat

In a webapp deployed in tomcat with security manager, this works:

```
URL url = servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/internal/tika/tika-app-1.2.jar");
// test to see if the content can be read
String test = IOUtils.toString(url);
```

Tomcat uses jndi for internal URLs. According to tomcat documentation about security manager (link [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html)), there is an implicit permission granted to resources inside the war file.

However, this doesn't work:

```
URL url = servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/internal/tika/tika-app-1.2.jar");
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url }, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
// load a class from the jar
Class<TextExtractor> clz = (Class) cl.loadClass(" ... some class ...");
delegate = clz.newInstance();
```

The exception that I get is this:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (org.apache.naming.JndiPermission jndi:/localhost/my_webapp/WEB-INF/internal/tika/tika-app-1.2.jar)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$4.run(URLClassLoader.java:515)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.getPermissions(URLClassLoader.java:513)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(SecureClassLoader.java:235)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at com.sample.myClass.afterPropertiesSet(TikaWrapper.java:38)
```

I guess my first question is: **why**?

If I add this to catalina.policy file then it works:

```
permission org.apache.naming.JndiPermission "jndi:/localhost/my_webapp/WEB-INF/internal/tika/tika-app-1.2.jar";
```

However, the client is not willing or can't change his policy file.

My second question is: any idea what to do? I can't put the jar under /WEB-INF/lib, otherwise I'd done it already.
I can put it outside tomcat all together and load it with a file:// based URL, but I am trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question, there is a [small note](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Running_under_a_security_manager) about class loading when running under a security manager in the documentation, citing it here for convenience:

> When running under a security manager the locations from which classes are permitted to be loaded will also depend on the contents of your policy file.

So it appears that by default a webapp classloader is allowed to load classes from WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes directories **only**. In your case, it looks like you're assigning the webapp classloader as a parent to your custom classloader, and therefore the latter, same as its parent, is only able to load classes from WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes.

As for what to do, since client doesn't want or can't change the policy file, consider trying to change the policy programmatically. There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737971/programmatically-grant-permissions-without-using-policy-file). However, it will only work if the current set of permissions allows to call `java.security.Permission.setPolicy`() method, and I bet it doesn't because that would set a JVM-system wide policy.