# JFXPanel security exception

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I updated to `1.7.0_67-b01` and now it seems I can't embed a JavaFX panel in my swing application.
This is the exception I get.
Anyone knows a workaround?

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.macosx.embedded" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at webview.WebBrowserFX.<init>(WebBrowserFX.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at baf.ui.WebView.initializeFXWebView(Unknown Source)
    at baf.ui.WebView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at mypackage.MyClass.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is it ordinary application, jnlp or applet?

Comment: Yes it's ordinary jnlp application

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your policy file (`$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/javaws.policy`) to include permissions to write this property. So, you should add this line to `javaws.policy`:

```
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "javafx.macosx.embedded", "write";
```

It seems to be the [old bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14936)

Comment: But I don't need a policy file. The application is signed. Also how would I force all the users to modify their policy file?

Comment: I checked the bug, Oracle says that this is not a issue! Although the bug is old this occurs only with update 67. With 65 it works.

Comment: Then I have to ask on how do you deploy your application. I would recommend just using "javafxpackager -deploy".

Comment: It's a swing application. The user has just to hit the jnlp, and Javaws would take care the rest. By the way I tested Java 8 Update 20, and it works also, no issue. It's not a bug according oracle, so oracle  never fixed and never will, and yet the error occurs in some java versions!

Comment: That's okay, javafxpackager creates jnlp too

Answer (score 0):

I tried what's suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737971/programmatically-grant-permissions-without-using-policy-file) and it works.

I add the permission programmatically.

```
PropertyPermission propertyPermission = new PropertyPermission("javafx.macosx.embedded", "write");
```

However the permissions of the orginal policy are lost.